# arcgisscripting in CGI script

Tags: python, apache, arcpy

I'm trying to write a Python script that imports `arcgisscripting` (stuck on 9.3.1 here) which is then run as CGI by a web app. It runs fine from the Windows command line but as soon as I drop it into the app it throws an `Error 500: Internal Server Error`. I checked the Apache logs and sure enough there's a `ImportError: No module named arcgisscripting`. All of my other modules are working fine (sys, os, etc.) Does anybody know what could be the issue here?

**Update**: I think it might have something to do with this: [Why can't python find some modules when I'm running CGI scripts from the web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783887/why-cant-python-find-some-modules-when-im-running-cgi-scripts-from-the-web)

Comment: Did you try the solution offered in your update? Make sure your arcgisscripting module is globally available to all users on your machine.

Comment: Just did - problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link in the question had the answer... The location of `arcgisscripting` is defined in the Windows environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. By printing `sys.path` from a CGI script I could tell this was missing from the variables Apache was using. Easy fix: add this to `httpd.conf`:

`SetEnv PYTHONPATH "c:/path/to/pythonpath"`

And no more `ImportError`!